# How to use keyboard shortcut ⌘ + [ on non-English Keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications, bettertouchtool

A MacOS application I use ([Notion](https://www.notion.so/)) employs keyboard shortcuts <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> as "Back" and "Forward" between pages.

However, I'm using a Swedish Keyboard, and I don't understand how to access these shortcuts.

On my Swedish keyboard, <kbd>[</kbd> is given by <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd>. 
Literally pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd> does not yield <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>.

NB: I am an owner of BetterTouchTool, and I tried some different tricks to create alternative keyboard shortcuts to do this, but I couldn't come up with a successful method. The application unfortunately doesn't provide App Menu options for the actions of going Back and Forward, so I can't bind shortcuts to App Menu options.

Comment: Sometimes the positions stay the same, even if the characters are different. Try Cmd plus the next two keys to the right of P.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the tip – that worked for one of the keys because it doesn't have a ⌘ use! But not for the other.

Comment: Last-ditch hope before someone who actually knows the answer finds it - try Cmd/shift/working key or cmd/alt - just in case...

Comment: Thanks. That didn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: Check in Safari what it shows in the History menu for Back & Forward. It's quite likely to use the same keys.

Comment: Am I right in assumng that you are looking for a specific keyboard shortcut, perhaps InDesign's Arrange>Bring Forward / Send Backward? If that's the case, there may not be any way to resolve your problem on a non-English keyboard, besides creating a keyboard shortcut in the software in question.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem with BetterTouchTool, but it doesn't really address the question of my OP. The app is written to use Trackpad three-finger swipes as Back/Forward – so I was able to bind custom keyboard shortcuts to trigger those Trackpad actions. However, it's not accomplished via ⌘ + [ or ⌘ + ].